# How to check if certain class methods have been called from within the same class

Tags: python, class, methods

I have some code that looks like this:

```
class Template:
    def insert_text(self, text):
        # code goes here
        return

    def insert_photo(self, path_to_photo):
        # some more code goes here
        return
    
    def compose(self):
        # this composes/generates the text file based on the above methods
        return       

customfile = Template()
text = customfile.insert_text("look at this code work!!!")
photo = customfile.insert_photo("C:/Users/...")
customfile.compose()
```

What I want to have happen, is that if the user calls the `compose` method on the `customfile` instance, that the `compose` method somehow looks up what other methods were called on the `customfile` instance, and then includes the results of those calls in the final result.

So basically I want the `compose` method to know what to include in the generated text file. e.g. The photo that I inserted in the above code, I want the `compose` method to know about that photo.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've read, but adding a `list` as a member variable is exactly how this is done.  Add an `__init__` function where you set `self.contents = []`, then append to that within the `insert` methods.

Comment: `compose` should not care about which methods are called. It *should* care about the objects created by those methods which are the things it will combine into the final result. `Template` should basically be a container for text, photos, etc, with information about where they should appear in the final page. `compose` will take the contents of the container and return the final page.

Comment: Functions keep references to the global scope of the module they are defined in. You are seem to have a lot of incorrect assumptions about how scopes work, so it's not clear that you are rejecting any of your other ideas for valid reasons.

Comment: After some more testing, I did find out that the statement about "lists inside classes" was false. That was just an assumption on my part, and I apologize for it. I will edit the question and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include a `list` as an instance variable? You can append all the results of the other methods to it and then when `compose` is called, you can process those results how you wish.

Something like:

```
class Template:

    def __init__(self):
        self.call_stack = []

    def insert_text(self, text):
        # code goes here
        self.call_stack.append(result)
        return

    def insert_photo(self, path_to_photo):
        # some more code goes here
        return
    
    def compose(self):
        # this composes/generates the text file based on the above methods
        for result in self.call_stack:
            # Do something (I assume add the elements to template in order)
        return       

customfile = Template()
text = customfile.insert_text("look at this code work!!!")
photo = customfile.insert_photo("C:/Users/...")
customfile.compose()
```

You mentioned that you can't use a list due to Python's scoping rules. I am not sure what you mean, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

We can make a `methods_called` `dict`ionary where its values represent the results (as a list of all the results) and number of times each method was called:

```
class Template:

    def __init__(self):
        self.methods_called = {method:{'calls': 0, 'results': []} for method in dir(Template) if not method.startswith('__') and method != 'compose'}

    def insert_text(self):
        # code goes here
        result = 19
        self.methods_called[self.insert_text.__name__]['calls'] += 1
        self.methods_called[self.insert_text.__name__]['results'].append(result)
        return

    def insert_photo(self):
        # some more code goes here
        result = 15
        self.methods_called[self.insert_photo.__name__]['calls'] += 1
        self.methods_called[self.insert_photo.__name__]['results'].append(result)
        return
    
    def compose(self):
        # this composes/generates the text file based on the above methods
        return self.methods_called

m = Template()
m.insert_photo()
m.insert_text()
m.insert_photo()
print(m.compose())
```

Outputs:

```
{'insert_photo': {'calls': 2, 'results': [15, 15]}, 'insert_text': {'calls': 1, 'results': [19]}}
```